# Can't install elementary OS 5.1 on Acer Predator Helios 300

Tags: system-installation, release-hera, acer

Trying to install on my new laptop and I am getting the following error upon trying add a partition:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-partman.py", line 1298, in on_partition_list_new_activate
    self.partman_dialog(devpart, partition)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/plugin.py", line 48, in wrapper
    return target(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-partman.py", line 961, in partman_dialog
    if create and partition['parted']['type'] == 'pri/log':
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have this error during installation or after?

Comment: Are you trying to dual boot or Elementary as a primary OS?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot install this on this model, it will cause the gpu to stop working